# Boolean operators and condition checks in C# - order of presedence

Tags: c#, logic, operator-precedence

I'm looking at some C# source code trying to trace a bug and relying on my basic understanding of programming and msdn to decipher, as I have no experience developing with it. At a key point that the buggy behavior must pass through, I found the following:

```
public static bool isObjectSpecialCheck(object someObject)
{
    string someParam = getParam(someObject);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someParam))
    {
        someParam = getParamSomewhereElse(someObject);
    }
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(someParam)))
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramIsSpecial(someParam)))
                return (true);
            else
                return (false);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            GlobalConstants.Log(log, "Error", "isObjectSpecialCheck", ex);
            return (false);
        }
    }
    return (false);
}
```

I have swapped out the original variables with dummies to try and keep the question abstract. What I'm noticing is that `.isNullOrEmpty` is used three distinct ways:

- `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someParam))`
- `if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(someParam)))`
- `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramIsSpecial(someParam)))`

The first uses `String` as the type, first letter capitalized, and does not use a negation.

The second has the negation outside parenthesis and is only passing in a defined variable to the method.

The third has the negation right beside the expression, with the `IsNullOrEmpty` being passed a function.

So I guess my questions are: Do these distinctions make a difference in general? Do they appear to be required/intentional in the above code? If they do make slight difference but the above choices appear to be style-choices from different contributors, what are the potential logical errors that could result?

The bug I am tracking down might occur if the above always returned true, even when it shouldn't. I'm wondering if 99% of the time the above would return true or false as expected  but would return a false true if a specific value were given (maybe 0 or a string literal 'NULL', etc).

Comment: The only case for this method to return true is when the method paramIsSpecial returns false, so i would investigate how is formed the return value of that method. (String and string are the same thing and negation of boolean values works as in every other programming language). Also the IsNullOrEmpty in the third case receives the return value of paramIsSpecial not the function

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it matters if the negation operator is there or missing.  None of the other differences are relevant.

`string` is simply an alias for `System.String`.  It doesn't matter which you use.

The use of parenthesis around the method call in the second example isn't needed; it is no different than omitting them, as in the third example.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is an alias for `System.String`, so there is no difference between those two, similar to how `int` and `Int32` are the same thing.

The negation syntax also does not matter, as it is applying negation to the entire quantity when the extra parentheses are used. Remove it if it is confusing or distracting, leave it in otherwise.

Unfortunately, it sounds like you are going to need to set break points and walk through the code until you find out where the logic is wrong or the data you are processing is wrong. You might also consider putting `Console` debugging statements in the 3 branches of concern and then viewing the results to see which path(s) are being taken by your data.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue could be that `String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)` would return false if `str` is only whitespace (ex. " ").  If your logic is wanting to treat a space as "empty", you would want to trim the string first.  It's imposible to tell if this is the actual issue with the limited details you can provide, but something to lookout for none the less.